# Duplicate Tracks in "Music" App

Tags: ipad

I used ITunes to download to my new IPad3 a variety of songs and albums I had already purchased.  However, in some cases, I have two copies of every song.  When I play an album with the "Music" app, I can see two copies of each song - and yes it plays both copies as it moves forward.

I've seen instructions online of [how to get rid of ITunes duplicates on a PC](http://garagesalepreview.com/how-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-songs-in-itunes/).  But I'm dealing with my IPad3, not a PC.

Comment: You're sure you don't have duplicate tracks in iTunes as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the Genius bar at the Apple store.  They simply had me delete the songs from my IPad, and re-download them.  The duplicate tracks problem was solved.  Thus both creating this problem and solving this problem required no connection to a PC or any other device.

In short, the problem was entirely within the IPad / ITunes synchronization.  It is VERY GOOD to know this remedy for this problem!!!

Comment: Not much help if you have thousands of songs and they're all duplciated. It could take a month to delete them all.

Answer (score 0):

You should have duplicate tracks on iTunes as well. If not, then try this out

- Plug in you iPad and open iTunes.
- On the "File" Menu Click on "Transfer Purchases from Brent's iPad" (I
  Assumed the name of your iPad but you get the point).
- Wait for sometime for all of your purchased tracks to transfer into
  you computer (PC right?).
- After that you can try out the steps mentioned in the link you
  posted. This will erase all the duplicates from your iTunes Library.
- After all is done, Sync you iPad and your duplicates should have been erased.

Hope it works!