# Kindle on IPad Not Syncing Notes

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, kindle

I've loaded the kindle app onto my IPad3.  I've made notes and highlights within that app, and I've given plenty opportunity for those to sync with Amazon...so that I can download those notes onto my kindle app on my PC.

But the only thing about this kindle-app-on-IPad that syncs successfully is the "furthest page read."  All my notes and highlights are not syncing.  How do I resolve this?

Now for a segue from my question...

I'm noticing a pattern here.  The IPad...

1. [Can't sync OneNote correctly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/how-to-force-ipad-onenote-re-sync)
2. [Can't sync ITunes correctly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47404/duplicate-tracks-in-music-app)
3. [Can't sync its own Calendar correctly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47650/delete-group-meeting-from-calendar)
4. and now it can't sync the Kindle correctly

In short, I don't think the IPad is a proper "connected" device.  I'm at a point where I would recommend a Galaxy or Windows tablet to others...

**Update**
I went to the Genius bar at the Apple store.  These various problems are mostly resoled.  See separate links above for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting and re-loading a Kindle book from a device, such as a reader on my PC or the book from my Kindle, somehow causes the notes to finally come down to the desired device.  Evidently the IPad had sent the notes up to whisper net, but Amazon didn't push those notes to other devices.

In short, this is more an Amazon problem than an IPad issue.